# Weird problem with CUDA installation

Tags: sudo, nvidia, libraries

I am experiencing a rather unusual problem with my CUDA installation on Linux Mint 18.3. After a clean reboot, running [deviceQuery](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) as a standard user: `optirun ./deviceQuery` returns FAIL, **but** if I do:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libcuda1-390
sudo optirun ./deviceQuery
```

Then everything works, running `optirun ./deviceQuery` again returns PASS.

What does `sudo` do that *solves* the problem (just reinstalling `libcuda1-390` does not help)?

I am using bumblebee to run programs on-demand with the graphics card.

Edit: I am also suspecting the bumblebee installation to be somehow faulty, not CUDA itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing `nvidia-modprobe`.

Comment: Care to explain the reason for the downvote? I guess I had a permission problem regarding the process of on-demand loading of nVidia driver. Somehow, `nvidia-modprobe`, which loads the nVidia kernel module and creates char device files, solved this problem.